# Defining a line between two points on a scatterplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies if this question is a duplicate; Looking up "drawing a line between two points" on Stack Overflow gave me some ideas, but I'm not sure how to apply them to my specific problem.

Let's say that my data take the shape of:

```
x <- runif(n = 10)
y <- runif(n = 10)
graphData <- data.frame(x, y)
graphData

           x          y
1  0.3328235 0.30122890
2  0.4886130 0.06072057
3  0.9544738 0.94772694
4  0.4829024 0.72059627
5  0.8903502 0.14229430
6  0.9144382 0.54928466
7  0.6087350 0.95409124
8  0.4106898 0.58548335
9  0.1470947 0.40451028
10 0.9352998 0.64789348
```

Then I do a scatterplot of those data:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(graphData, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

What I want is, to draw exactly one line, connecting the point that has the highest y-value with the point that has the highest x-value. (The example makes it look like those could be the same point, but in my real-life data, the odds of that happening are infinitesimally small.)

Also, I'm not just drawing the line on a plot; I will also need to provide that line as a formula, to be used in a separate analysis. Thoughts?

Comment: I would filter the data to have just those two points, and then use that as the `data` argument to `geom_path`. That way you can also do whatever you need with it as a formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try:

```
p <- ggplot(graphData, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(x == max(x) | y == max(y)), method = lm)
p
```

and then call the formula of the line:

```
lm(y ~ x, data = graphData %>% filter(x == max(x) | y == max(y)))
```